# GIT "stop tracking" not working using source tree

Tags: git, atlassian-sourcetree

I have some files specific to my development on my machine. That files would not need to go on live. To do so I did the following:

Right clicked the file "Working copy section" and clicked Stop Tracking. The file goes upward. From the upward panel I again clicked "Stop tracking" from the upward panel. The file delete from my disc.

I want to do all this because until I do not commit I can't pull the code.

I tried with every possible actions available in sourcetree. But either it overwrote the live file or delete the live or delete my copy or overwrote my copy.

I just want to remove that file from tracking.

Any kind of help is appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add those files to your .gitignore file, or to your global git ignore settings file.

See also http://git-scm.com/docs/gitignore